# Flutter Broadcast Event to other device

Tags: dart, flutter, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I am currently working with Flutter project.

I have been through a lot of tutorial and website but I do not see those learning materials are achieving what I need.

For example, User A and User B are using my app. I wanted to create an event from User A to User B like a dialog box will shown u at the screen of User B app.

I have did the same thing with my Laravel project which work with pusher and it works flawlessly.

Is there any library for me to build the same thing in Flutter for ios and android too?

I really need some suggestion from you guys about this.

Thanks

Comment: How about flutter with socket.io?

Comment: Hi Kenneth sorry for the late reply, I wonder if socket.io can do it or not. cause both User A and User B are clients. By far, the tutorial that I have been going through is only showing me how flutter use socket.io to communicate with the server.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a socket.io server, which is usually installed in a linux server.  Otherwise how can A knows the ip and port of B, since B may be using an internal ip address which is behind a firewall and/or router.  Even if B is using mobile network connection, some mobile operators only provide internal ip address instead of public ip address.

Comment: In my previous audio/video/text chat app developed by Cordova, I used WebRTC to achieve peer to peer communication to allow users communicate with each other without a socket server, in this case, you still need a STUN server(pls. google STUN) to 'find' the ip and port of another user.  Many Free STUN servers are available so that you don't need to install your own socket server.  however, STUN can only create 85 to 90% of successful connection between peers, you still need to install your own TURN server for cases like one of the user is behind a 'strong firewall' which blocks STUN.

Comment: I believe socket.io is quite easy to implement, I was able to install socket.io using 'linux' servers such as: pc, nas (with Intel cpu), raspberry pi 3b+, or even a rooted old Android mobile phone with 'Linux Deploy' installed.  of course, this linux server must have public ip address and is behind a router with port redirect function(nat or virtual server)